# TASK [common : Pulling common images]

Tags: docker, openstack, kolla-ansible

I'm trying to install openstack wallaby with kolla-ansible. I followed this document https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/user/quickstart.html and
https://docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/latest/user/multinode.html to deploy multinode.

I created a local registry

```
docker run -d \
 --name registry \
 --restart=always \
 -p 4000:5000 \
 -v registry:/var/lib/registry \
 registry:2
```

docker ps -a show

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
ea8b5750b84a   hello-world   "/hello"                 30 minutes ago   Exited (0) 30 minutes ago             eloquent_poincare
4e1a2028653f   registry:2    "/entrypoint.sh /etc…"   17 hours ago     Up 3 hours                            registry
```

so that i try to push image to my local registry

```
kolla-build --base ubuntu --type binary --registry 10.102.196.118:4000 --push
```

and it shows

TASK [common : Pulling common images] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [controller] (item={'key': 'fluentd', 'value': {'container_name': 'fluentd', 'group': 'fluentd', 'enabled': True, 'image': '10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-fluentd:wallaby', 'environment': {'KOLLA_CONFIG_STRATEGY': 'COPY_ALWAYS'}, 'volumes': ['/etc/kolla/fluentd/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro', '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro', '/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro', 'kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/', 'fluentd_data:/var/lib/fluentd/data/'], 'dimensions': {}}}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "item": {"key": "fluentd", "value": {"container_name": "fluentd", "dimensions": {}, "enabled": true, "environment": {"KOLLA_CONFIG_STRATEGY": "COPY_ALWAYS"}, "group": "fluentd", "image": "10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-fluentd:wallaby", "volumes": ["/etc/kolla/fluentd/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro", "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro", "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro", "kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/", "fluentd_data:/var/lib/fluentd/data/"]}}, "msg": "'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 268, in _raise_for_status\n    response.raise_for_status()\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status\n    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)\nrequests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-fluentd\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_bjjz7o8w/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 1199, in main\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_bjjz7o8w/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 649, in pull_image\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 430, in pull\n    self._raise_for_status(response)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 270, in _raise_for_status\n    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception\n    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)\ndocker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-fluentd: Internal Server Error ("Get http://10.102.196.118:4000/v2/: dial tcp 10.102.196.118:4000: connect: connection refused")\n'"}
failed: [compute01] (item={'key': 'fluentd', 'value': {'container_name': 'fluentd', 'group': 'fluentd', 'enabled': True, 'image': '10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-fluentd:wallaby', 'environment': {'KOLLA_CONFIG_STRATEGY': 'COPY_ALWAYS'}, 'volumes': ['/etc/kolla/fluentd/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro', '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro', '/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro', 'kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/', 'fluentd_data:/var/lib/fluentd/data/'], 'dimensions': {}}}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "item": {"key": "fluentd", "value": {"container_name": "fluentd", "dimensions": {}, "enabled": true, "environment": {"KOLLA_CONFIG_STRATEGY": "COPY_ALWAYS"}, "group": "fluentd", "image": "10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-fluentd:wallaby", "volumes": ["/etc/kolla/fluentd/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro", "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro", "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro", "kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/", "fluentd_data:/var/lib/fluentd/data/"]}}, "msg": "'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 268, in _raise_for_status\n    response.raise_for_status()\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status\n    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)\nrequests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-fluentd\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_em961l9o/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 1199, in main\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_em961l9o/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 649, in pull_image\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 430, in pull\n    self._raise_for_status(response)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 270, in _raise_for_status\n    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception\n    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)\ndocker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-fluentd: Internal Server Error ("Get http://10.102.196.118:4000/v2/: dial tcp 10.102.196.118:4000: connect: connection refused")\n'"}
failed: [compute02] (item={'key': 'fluentd', 'value': {'container_name': 'fluentd', 'group': 'fluentd', 'enabled': True, 'image': '10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-fluentd:wallaby', 'environment': {'KOLLA_CONFIG_STRATEGY': 'COPY_ALWAYS'}, 'volumes': ['/etc/kolla/fluentd/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro', '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro', '/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro', 'kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/', 'fluentd_data:/var/lib/fluentd/data/'], 'dimensions': {}}}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "item": {"key": "fluentd", "value": {"container_name": "fluentd", "dimensions": {}, "enabled": true, "environment": {"KOLLA_CONFIG_STRATEGY": "COPY_ALWAYS"}, "group": "fluentd", "image": "10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-fluentd:wallaby", "volumes": ["/etc/kolla/fluentd/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro", "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro", "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro", "kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/", "fluentd_data:/var/lib/fluentd/data/"]}}, "msg": "'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 268, in _raise_for_status\n    response.raise_for_status()\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status\n    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)\nrequests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-fluentd\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_r459m9qj/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 1199, in main\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_r459m9qj/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 649, in pull_image\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 430, in pull\n    self._raise_for_status(response)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 270, in _raise_for_status\n    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception\n    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)\ndocker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-fluentd: Internal Server Error ("Get http://10.102.196.118:4000/v2/: dial tcp 10.102.196.118:4000: connect: connection refused")\n'"}
failed: [compute01] (item={'key': 'kolla-toolbox', 'value': {'container_name': 'kolla_toolbox', 'group': 'kolla-toolbox', 'enabled': True, 'image': '10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-kolla-toolbox:wallaby', 'environment': {'ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR': '1', 'ANSIBLE_LIBRARY': '/usr/share/ansible'}, 'privileged': True, 'volumes': ['/etc/kolla/kolla-toolbox/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro', '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro', '/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro', '/dev/:/dev/', '/run/:/run/:shared', 'kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/', '/run/openvswitch:/run/openvswitch:shared'], 'dimensions': {}}}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "item": {"key": "kolla-toolbox", "value": {"container_name": "kolla_toolbox", "dimensions": {}, "enabled": true, "environment": {"ANSIBLE_LIBRARY": "/usr/share/ansible", "ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR": "1"}, "group": "kolla-toolbox", "image": "10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-kolla-toolbox:wallaby", "privileged": true, "volumes": ["/etc/kolla/kolla-toolbox/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro", "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro", "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro", "/dev/:/dev/", "/run/:/run/:shared", "kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/", "/run/openvswitch:/run/openvswitch:shared"]}}, "msg": "'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 268, in _raise_for_status\n    response.raise_for_status()\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status\n    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)\nrequests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-kolla-toolbox\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_i1vw3h3y/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 1199, in main\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_i1vw3h3y/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 649, in pull_image\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 430, in pull\n    self._raise_for_status(response)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 270, in _raise_for_status\n    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception\n    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)\ndocker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-kolla-toolbox: Internal Server Error ("Get http://10.102.196.118:4000/v2/: dial tcp 10.102.196.118:4000: connect: connection refused")\n'"}
failed: [compute02] (item={'key': 'kolla-toolbox', 'value': {'container_name': 'kolla_toolbox', 'group': 'kolla-toolbox', 'enabled': True, 'image': '10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-kolla-toolbox:wallaby', 'environment': {'ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR': '1', 'ANSIBLE_LIBRARY': '/usr/share/ansible'}, 'privileged': True, 'volumes': ['/etc/kolla/kolla-toolbox/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro', '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro', '/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro', '/dev/:/dev/', '/run/:/run/:shared', 'kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/', '/run/openvswitch:/run/openvswitch:shared'], 'dimensions': {}}}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "item": {"key": "kolla-toolbox", "value": {"container_name": "kolla_toolbox", "dimensions": {}, "enabled": true, "environment": {"ANSIBLE_LIBRARY": "/usr/share/ansible", "ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR": "1"}, "group": "kolla-toolbox", "image": "10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-kolla-toolbox:wallaby", "privileged": true, "volumes": ["/etc/kolla/kolla-toolbox/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro", "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro", "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro", "/dev/:/dev/", "/run/:/run/:shared", "kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/", "/run/openvswitch:/run/openvswitch:shared"]}}, "msg": "'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 268, in _raise_for_status\n    response.raise_for_status()\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status\n    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)\nrequests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-kolla-toolbox\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_fhy2h219/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 1199, in main\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_fhy2h219/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 649, in pull_image\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 430, in pull\n    self._raise_for_status(response)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 270, in _raise_for_status\n    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception\n    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)\ndocker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-kolla-toolbox: Internal Server Error ("Get http://10.102.196.118:4000/v2/: dial tcp 10.102.196.118:4000: connect: connection refused")\n'"}
failed: [controller] (item={'key': 'kolla-toolbox', 'value': {'container_name': 'kolla_toolbox', 'group': 'kolla-toolbox', 'enabled': True, 'image': '10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-kolla-toolbox:wallaby', 'environment': {'ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR': '1', 'ANSIBLE_LIBRARY': '/usr/share/ansible'}, 'privileged': True, 'volumes': ['/etc/kolla/kolla-toolbox/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro', '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro', '/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro', '/dev/:/dev/', '/run/:/run/:shared', 'kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/', '/run/openvswitch:/run/openvswitch:shared'], 'dimensions': {}}}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "item": {"key": "kolla-toolbox", "value": {"container_name": "kolla_toolbox", "dimensions": {}, "enabled": true, "environment": {"ANSIBLE_LIBRARY": "/usr/share/ansible", "ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR": "1"}, "group": "kolla-toolbox", "image": "10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-kolla-toolbox:wallaby", "privileged": true, "volumes": ["/etc/kolla/kolla-toolbox/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro", "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro", "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro", "/dev/:/dev/", "/run/:/run/:shared", "kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/", "/run/openvswitch:/run/openvswitch:shared"]}}, "msg": "'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 268, in _raise_for_status\n    response.raise_for_status()\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status\n    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)\nrequests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-kolla-toolbox\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_lwwkuzxg/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 1199, in main\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_lwwkuzxg/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 649, in pull_image\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 430, in pull\n    self._raise_for_status(response)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 270, in _raise_for_status\n    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception\n    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)\ndocker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-kolla-toolbox: Internal Server Error ("Get http://10.102.196.118:4000/v2/: dial tcp 10.102.196.118:4000: connect: connection refused")\n'"}
failed: [compute02] (item={'key': 'cron', 'value': {'container_name': 'cron', 'group': 'cron', 'enabled': True, 'image': '10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-cron:wallaby', 'environment': {'DUMMY_ENVIRONMENT': 'kolla_useless_env'}, 'volumes': ['/etc/kolla/cron/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro', '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro', '/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro', 'kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/'], 'dimensions': {}}}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "item": {"key": "cron", "value": {"container_name": "cron", "dimensions": {}, "enabled": true, "environment": {"DUMMY_ENVIRONMENT": "kolla_useless_env"}, "group": "cron", "image": "10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-cron:wallaby", "volumes": ["/etc/kolla/cron/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro", "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro", "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro", "kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/"]}}, "msg": "'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 268, in _raise_for_status\n    response.raise_for_status()\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status\n    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)\nrequests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-cron\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_6iio6rgh/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 1199, in main\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_6iio6rgh/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 649, in pull_image\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 430, in pull\n    self._raise_for_status(response)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 270, in _raise_for_status\n    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception\n    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)\ndocker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-cron: Internal Server Error ("Get http://10.102.196.118:4000/v2/: dial tcp 10.102.196.118:4000: connect: connection refused")\n'"}
failed: [controller] (item={'key': 'cron', 'value': {'container_name': 'cron', 'group': 'cron', 'enabled': True, 'image': '10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-cron:wallaby', 'environment': {'DUMMY_ENVIRONMENT': 'kolla_useless_env'}, 'volumes': ['/etc/kolla/cron/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro', '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro', '/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro', 'kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/'], 'dimensions': {}}}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "item": {"key": "cron", "value": {"container_name": "cron", "dimensions": {}, "enabled": true, "environment": {"DUMMY_ENVIRONMENT": "kolla_useless_env"}, "group": "cron", "image": "10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-cron:wallaby", "volumes": ["/etc/kolla/cron/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro", "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro", "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro", "kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/"]}}, "msg": "'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 268, in _raise_for_status\n    response.raise_for_status()\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status\n    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)\nrequests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-cron\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_de6juvjn/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 1199, in main\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_de6juvjn/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 649, in pull_image\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 430, in pull\n    self._raise_for_status(response)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 270, in _raise_for_status\n    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception\n    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)\ndocker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-cron: Internal Server Error ("Get http://10.102.196.118:4000/v2/: dial tcp 10.102.196.118:4000: connect: connection refused")\n'"}
failed: [compute01] (item={'key': 'cron', 'value': {'container_name': 'cron', 'group': 'cron', 'enabled': True, 'image': '10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-cron:wallaby', 'environment': {'DUMMY_ENVIRONMENT': 'kolla_useless_env'}, 'volumes': ['/etc/kolla/cron/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro', '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro', '/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro', 'kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/'], 'dimensions': {}}}) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "item": {"key": "cron", "value": {"container_name": "cron", "dimensions": {}, "enabled": true, "environment": {"DUMMY_ENVIRONMENT": "kolla_useless_env"}, "group": "cron", "image": "10.102.196.118:4000/kolla/ubuntu-binary-cron:wallaby", "volumes": ["/etc/kolla/cron/:/var/lib/kolla/config_files/:ro", "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro", "/etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro", "kolla_logs:/var/log/kolla/"]}}, "msg": "'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 268, in _raise_for_status\n    response.raise_for_status()\n  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status\n    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)\nrequests.exceptions.HTTPError: 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url: http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-cron\n\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\n\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_szmrt81h/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 1199, in main\n  File "/tmp/ansible_kolla_docker_payload_szmrt81h/ansible_kolla_docker_payload.zip/ansible/modules/kolla_docker.py", line 649, in pull_image\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/image.py", line 430, in pull\n    self._raise_for_status(response)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 270, in _raise_for_status\n    raise create_api_error_from_http_exception(e)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in create_api_error_from_http_exception\n    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation)\ndocker.errors.APIError: 500 Server Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.41/images/create?tag=wallaby&fromImage=10.102.196.118%3A4000%2Fkolla%2Fubuntu-binary-cron: Internal Server Error ("Get http://10.102.196.118:4000/v2/: dial tcp 10.102.196.118:4000: connect: connection refused")\n'"}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
compute01                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
compute02                  : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
controller                 : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0

Command failed ansible-playbook -i multinode -e @/etc/kolla/globals.yml  -e @/etc/kolla/passwords.yml -e CONFIG_DIR=/etc/kolla  -e kolla_action=pull /usr/local/share/kolla-ansible/ansible/site.yml

**UPDATED**

```
$ curl http://10.102.196.118:4000
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.102.196.118 port 4000: Connection refused
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
    $ ss
icmp6     UNCONN     0          0                                                                                                 *:ipv6-icmp                       *:*
icmp6     UNCONN     0          0                                                                                                 *:ipv6-icmp                       *:*
udp       ESTAB      0          0                                                                             10.102.196.118%ens160:bootpc               10.102.196.1:bootps
tcp       ESTAB      0          0                                                                                    10.102.196.118:ssh                 192.168.20.22:27125
tcp       ESTAB      0          64                                                                                   10.102.196.118:ssh                 192.168.20.22:62537
v_str     ESTAB      0          0                                                                                         962197598:1023                            0:976
~$ sudo netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      643/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      801/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      657/cupsd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      801/sshd: /usr/sbin
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      657/cupsd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           655/avahi-daemon: r
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           643/systemd-resolve
udp        0      0 192.168.1.10:123        0.0.0.0:*                           794/ntpd
udp        0      0 10.102.196.118:123      0.0.0.0:*                           794/ntpd
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           794/ntpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           794/ntpd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:631             0.0.0.0:*                           742/cups-browsed
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50187           0.0.0.0:*                           655/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*                                655/avahi-daemon: r
udp6       0      0 fe80::a5a2:a239:40c:123 :::*                                794/ntpd
udp6       0      0 fe80::63cf:2585:82a:123 :::*                                794/ntpd
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                                794/ntpd
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                794/ntpd
udp6       0      0 :::41366                :::*                                655/avahi-daemon: r
```

And i really don't know how to fix this. Can anyone help me?

Comment: "Connection refused" normally means that nothing listens at that port, but it can also be a reply by a firewall. Try accessing 10.102.196.118:4000 with curl to confirm this; check your network configuration starting with the `ss` command, to see if the registry does in fact listen, then check for any firewall blocking this port.

Comment: I disabled firewall before starting , and the ss command does not show that registry is listening

Comment: Obviously, your problem is caused by the registry not listening. Why does `docker ps` say that it is up? Perhaps restarting helps, or checking the registry's log?